# not able to revise paypal subscription

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to upgrade the plan of paypal subscription using Rest API.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_revise

This is the documentation I am following.

But I am getting the following error :

> {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","message":"The requested action could
>   not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business
>   validation.","debug_id":"9d40b8cfc8e6e","details":[{"issue":"PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS","description":"Payment
>   for the subscription is in
>   progress."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}

What Am I doing wrong as this subscription is active with 1 Day of recurring frequency

Comment: Did you find a solution? Im struggling with the same error

Comment: actually this is the issue with sandbox environment. Over real prod it works fine

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone runs into this. I contacted paypal Merchant Technical support about it. They finally got back to me (after a week).

### PayPal Response:

The error "PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS" is returned if you attempt to revise the billing details for a subscription within 24 hours of the next scheduled billing.

As the profile you referenced "_____________" has a daily billing cycle, you won't be able to revise the billing details for this subscription.  Instead, you would need to cancel the existing subscription and create a new one with the relevant billing details which you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should attempt to revise a subscription on a day when there is no payment in progress. For this to be possible, create a subscription that recurs less rapidly than every day.

Comment: I have also tried with a subscription of 30 days and upgrading it but it also fails with the same exception

Comment: Then your issue may be that it can't be done while the subscription is active